# Heavy archive log generation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.1

We are using PostgreSQL 9.1 in our production server. From the past one month, our database is generating nearly 35 GB of archive logs on a daily basis. For that, we have monitored what are all the queries are being run at the time of archive log generation. Then we ran vacuum(freeze,analyze) on the whole database. But it seems to be no effect on the archive log generation. We have suspected one table for this. Every 9th and 39th minute of an hour, same delete statement is being running. It is deleting the whole table each time it gets executed. For test purpose, we ran EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS) against the statement. We found that read = 576 MB and written = 328 MB. But, in our production server, shared_buffers = 24 MB.
So, each and every time it is taking 24 MB of data blocks from the disk to shared buffer. Then it will flush to disk and again it will take 24 MB of data blocks into the shared buffers.

So, is the reason of archive log generation is because of frequent flushing of data blocks ? Shall we need to increase shared_buffers in our production server to get rid of heavy archive log generation?
In our production server, work_mem = 1 MB
Here is the output of EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,BUFFERS) for your information:

```
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on table_a  (cost=83.35..171.85 rows=2060 width=12) (actual time=11949.929..11949.929 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=375963 read=73999 written=42030
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=83.35..171.85 rows=2060 width=12) (actual time=1.028..12.570 rows=2060 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (public.table_a.id = public.table_a.id)
         Buffers: shared hit=46 read=30 written=18
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..57.60 rows=2060 width=10) (actual time=0.007..5.009 rows=2060 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=7 read=30 written=18
         ->  Hash  (cost=57.60..57.60 rows=2060 width=10) (actual time=0.973..0.973 rows=2060 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 89kB
               Buffers: shared hit=37
               ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..57.60 rows=2060 width=10) (actual time=0.002..0.463 rows=2060 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=37
 Total runtime: 11950.028 ms
```

Comment: `shared_buffers = 24MB` is an **extremely** low setting. Are you running in some kind of restricted environment?

Comment: And one more thing, if we are going to increase the shared_buffers, then how will we recover the data in case of an instance crash?

Comment: Postgres manages that you don't have to worry. It does not put anything into the shared buffers that is not persisted  to disk. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-reliability.html

Comment: It seems you query is doing two self joins on the table which are responsible for much of the reads. Can you please also add the query itself?

Comment: explain (analyze,buffers) delete from table_a where id in (select id from table_a);

Comment: The subquery makes no sense. If `id` is `not null` the whole query is exactly the same as `delete from table_a` (which can be optimized to `truncate table_a`). If `id` is nullable it can be simplified to `delete from table_a where id is not null`

Comment: My actual query is like            explain (analyze,buffers) delete from table_a where id in (1,2,3,.........);

Comment: I dont have the full query thats why i posted like that. Just to get all id's, i have used the subquery

Comment: a simple `where id in (1,2,3..)` would not result in that execution plan.

Comment: And one more query, you have mentioned like Postgres manages that you don't have to worry. It does not put anything into the shared buffers that is not persisted to disk. This is ok if PostgreSQL is not modifying any data in the shared buffer. If PostgreSQL instance got crashed at the time of modifying data in the shared buffer, how can we recover?

Comment: Please read the link I added earlier: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-reliability.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-intro.html

> Briefly, WAL's central concept is that **changes to data files (where
>   tables and indexes reside) must be written only after those changes
>   have been logged**, that is, after log records describing the changes
>   have been flushed to permanent storage. If we follow this procedure,
>   we do not need to flush data pages to disk on every transaction
>   commit, because we know that in the event of a crash we will be able
>   to recover the database using the log: any changes that have not been
>   applied to the data pages can be redone from the log records. (This is
>   roll-forward recovery, also known as REDO.)

So in short `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, VACUUM, CLUSTER, ALTER.. SET TABLESPACE` (and other similar) produce WALs. As more blocks are rewritten as more WALs created. `shared_buffers` will not affect it.